# MySql Update statement (DDT-mygroupname)

Tags: c#, mysql

Database not updating, its just redirecting and not crashing
here is the code:

```
    protected void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;" + "pwd=password;database=ddt_data");
        conn.Open();

        string command = String.Format("update `fixture` set `referee`='" + this.txtRef.Text + "',`ScoreA`='" + this.txtScoreA.Text + "',`ScoreB`='" + this.txtScoreB.Text + "',`Winner`='" + this.txtWinner.Text + "' where `idfixture`='" + this.txtFixtureID.Text + "';", conn);
        //MySqlDataReader Reader;
        MySqlCommand Update = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
        Update.Connection = conn;


        //Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtDate.Text);
        //Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", txtTime.Text);
        //Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team A", txtTeamA.Text);
        //Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Team B", txtTeamB.Text);
        //Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Referee", txtRef.Text);
        //Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScoreA", txtScoreA.Text);
        //Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScoreB", txtScoreB.Text);
        //Update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Winner", txtWinner.Text);
        //Reader = Update.ExecuteReader();
        //while (Reader.Read()) 

        //{
        //}

        Update.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("FixtureEdit.aspx");

    }
```

Comment: Why dyd you remove the correct way to execute sql commands? (Parameters are the way to go, not string concatenation)

Comment: ok do i use parameters , and remove string.format ?

Comment: Why do you have single quotes around the table and column names?

Comment: Yes, you remove the string format and put placeholders like @xxxx where you want to pass the parameter, then fill the MySqlCommand.Parameters collection with the correct names for the parameters (the @xxxx) and the value for that parameter. Also remember that you cannot declare a parameter name with spaces "@Team A" is wrong "@TeamA" is correct. Finally, the most important thing. Parameters type should be correct. If you have a string field then a parameter value of type string is correct but if you have a number field then pass a number not a string

Comment: how do i pass a number not a string

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your CommandText values and used a parameterized SQL statement. Make sure that the parameter names match the list from below.

```
protected void cmdUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;" + 
        "pwd=password;database=ddt_data");
    conn.Open();
    string command = "UPDATE fixture SET referee=@referee, scorea=@scorea, " +
        "scoreb=@scoreb, winner=@winner WHERE idfixture=@idfixture";
    MySqlCommmand update = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@referee", this.txtRef.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scorea", this.txtScoreA.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scoreb", this.txtScoreB.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@winner", this.txtWinner.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("idfixture", this.txtFixtureID.Text);

    // not sure what you want to achieve from this
    // MySqlDataReader reader = update.ExecuteReader();
    // while (reader.Read())
    // {
         // do something here?
    // }

    update.ExecuteNonQuery(); // use this if you don't need the DataReader
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
    Response.Redirect("FixtureEdit.aspx");

}
```

Comment: @DAVIDSAMUEL I'm guessing that you're calling a method inside your Page Load event to display existing information. Use the if (!IsPostBack) statement so that records will not update to their original values.

Comment: yes i am doing that, i will try your solution quick